# In which part of the fridge should muscaris (grape hyacinths) be stored?

Tags: bulbs, storage, grape-hyacinth

I put my muscaris in the part of the fridge where I store fruits, but I heard that some people store them in the freezer where it's much colder.

However, won't the freezer freeze them to death? Which one is better?

Comment: Grape hyacinths in Hong Kong... wow!  From what I read, you got it right.

Answer (score 3):

Put them in the coldest part of the refrigerator, which is normally the part closest to the freezer. The freezer would be a little too cold and most of the refrigerator is too warm. 25-30 degrees Fahrenheit is usually best. If you keep your refrigerator below forty degrees, it will probably do fine.